# Flutter Navigation issue

Tags: flutter, navigation

I'm trying to handle navigations between pages in my flutter app depending on whether the user is logged in or not depending on the availability of the token sent by the server,

I've defined named routes in MaterialApp widget and I've overridden the initState of the landing page to check the availability of token in order to direct the user to the proper page

the problem is when the token is available , the user must be directed to the homePage but when I do the navigation using this line of code

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/home");
```

it does not work and show me the red screen with the message of

```
I/flutter (11990): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (11990): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state:
I/flutter (11990): _HomePageState#4a409(ticker inactive)):
I/flutter (11990): The method '/' was called on null.
I/flutter (11990): Receiver: null
I/flutter (11990): Tried calling: /(1080)
```

but when i direct the user to other named routes ,it works fine,
and also when I direct the user to the login page , I've already set the login page to check the availability of token and when it is found ,it also will direct the user to the home page via the same line of code written above and also works fine but when I try to direct him directly  the error written above pops up

anyone can help me fix this issue ?

Comment: did you define MaterialApp (home: HomePage () ) value as a HomePage ?

Comment: no ,the home is a temporary page that  inside it's initState method,  it will try connecting to sharedPreferences to check the existence of token and take actions accordingly